# is there an way to print values without spaces without using sep

Tags: python-3.x

i have been asked to print this palindromic triangle in just 2 lines of code and without using string literals , it raises an error when i try to use this sep="", so is there a way to print it in one single line.

output is:
[for the input 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfN2j.png)

for the input 5
and raises the error:
"invalid string literal found" by compiler though the answer is right
without sep parameter spaces are created and shows wrong output

for i in range(1,int(input())+1):

```
print(*range(1,i),i,*reversed(range(1,i)),sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `str()` to get the empty string instead of using literal

```py
In [87]: for i in range(1, 10):
    ...:     print(*range(1,i),i,*reversed(range(1,i)),sep=str())
    ...:
```

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
12345654321
1234567654321
123456787654321
12345678987654321
```

For other characters you may just use `chr(n)` where `n` is integer code of needed character:

```py
In [92]: chr(32) + str(1) + chr(10) + str(2)
Out[92]: ' 1\n2'
```